# Can you rename the "Option" label ? ( Chrome-Extension )

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried this : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html and made an option page.

So a selection has been added under my extension icon with the name of `Option`.

My question is that is there a way to rename `Option` and change it something like `Setting` or some words in other languages ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Options" label at `chrome://extensions` is automatically adapted to the user's language. Extensions cannot change the value of this label.

The value of the "Options" option at the dropdown menu at the extension's button cannot be customized either, but you can create a *new* context menu item under the button as of Chrome 38. E.g.

```js
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'show-settings', // or any other name
    title: 'Settings',
    contexts: ['page_action', 'browser_action']
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == 'show-settings') {
        chrome.tabs.create({
            url: chrome.runtime.getURL('settings.html')
        });
    }
});
```

I suggest to just stick to "Options" though, because users do already know what the option does. Consistency in UI/UX is important, imagine how you productive you'd be if every application had a different way of (e.g.) closing/quiting the application.

manifest.json to test the previous script:

```js
{
    "name": "Contextmenu on browserAction button",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Right-click to see a context menu"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easier way to trigger events.**

```js
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: 'GitHub',
  contexts: ['page_action'],
  onclick: () => console.log('GitHub'),
});
```